# Python learning - if, elif and else statement - certain condition is true but not get executed(printed), why?

Tags: python

Problem:
program doesn't execute the 2nd elif statement when the 2nd elif statement is true...why?

For an example,

input: 
enter ppl#1=100,ppl#2=31,ppl#3=30, it doesn't print out the statement (see 2nd elif statement)

expected output:
the oldest is: 100 and the youngest is: 30' ## this line is from the 2nd elif statement

```
ppl1=int(input('\r\n person #1: pls enter your age: '))
ppl2=int(input('\r\n person #2: pls enter your age: '))
ppl3=int(input('\r\n person #3: pls enter your age: '))

if (ppl3 > ppl1) and (ppl3 > ppl2): 
  if (ppl1 > ppl2):
    print(f'\r\n the oldest is:{ppl3} and the youngest is: {ppl2}')

elif ppl1 > ppl3 and ppl1> ppl2:
  if(ppl3 > ppl2):
    print(f'\r\n the oldest is:{ppl1} and the youngest is: {ppl2}')

elif (ppl1 > ppl3) and (ppl1 > ppl2): 
  if ppl2 > ppl3:
    print(f'\r\n the oldest is: {ppl1} and the youngest is: {ppl3}')

elif ppl3 > ppl1 and ppl3 > ppl2: 
  if(ppl2 > ppl1):
    print(f'\r\n the oldest is: {ppl3} and the youngest is: {ppl1}')

elif ppl2 > ppl1 and ppl2 > ppl3: 
  if(ppl3 > ppl1):
    print(f'\r\n the oldest is: {ppl2} and the youngest is: {ppl1}')

elif ppl2 > ppl1 and ppl2 > ppl3: 
  if ppl1 > ppl3:
    print(f'\r\n the oldest is: {ppl2} and the youngest is: {ppl3}')

else:
  print(f'\r\n The three people may be with the same age')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is brought by the nested `if` blocks:

```py
elif ppl1 > ppl3 and ppl1> ppl2:
  if(ppl3 > ppl2): # nested if block
    print(f'\r\n the oldest is:{ppl1} and the youngest is: {ppl2}')
```

The nested if blocks are not affected by the elif/else statements of the "parent" block. This basically means that once you enter here:

```
elif ppl1 > ppl3 and ppl1> ppl2:
```

The other elif/else statements are not considered anymore, no matter what the inner code does.

A solution to your problem is to avoid nesting if blocks and rather chain the conditions with `and` statements:

```
elif ppl1 > ppl3 and ppl1 > ppl2 and ppl3 > ppl2:
  print(f'\r\n the oldest is: {ppl1} and the youngest is: {ppl2}')
```

Or you can add an else to the inner if blocks:

```py
elif ppl1 > ppl3 and ppl1 > ppl2:
  if ppl3 > ppl2:
    print(f'\r\n the oldest is: {ppl1} and the youngest is: {ppl2}')
  else:
    print(...)
```

(Do the same for all the blocks)

Answer (score 2):

You have the same condition in multiple `if` and `elif` statements. When a condition is true, none of the following `elif` statements will be executed, so only the first one is used.

You need to nest your conditions rather than testing the same thing twice.

```
if (ppl3 > ppl1) and (ppl3 > ppl2): 
    if (ppl1 > ppl2):
        print(f'\r\n the oldest is:{ppl3} and the youngest is: {ppl2}')
    elif (ppl2 > ppl1):
        print(f'\r\n the oldest is: {ppl3} and the youngest is: {ppl1}')
    else:
        print(f'\r\n the oldest is: {ppl3} and {ppl1} and {ppl2} are the same age')

elif ppl1 > ppl3 and ppl1> ppl2:
    if(ppl3 > ppl2):
        print(f'\r\n the oldest is:{ppl1} and the youngest is: {ppl2}')
    elif ppl2 > ppl3:
        print(f'\r\n the oldest is: {ppl1} and the youngest is: {ppl3}')
    else:
        print(f'\r\n the oldest is: {ppl1} and {ppl2} and {ppl3} are the same age')

elif ppl2 > ppl1 and ppl2 > ppl3: 
    if(ppl3 > ppl1):
        print(f'\r\n the oldest is: {ppl2} and the youngest is: {ppl1}')
    elif ppl1 > ppl3:
        print(f'\r\n the oldest is: {ppl2} and the youngest is: {ppl3}')
    else:
        print(f'\r\n the oldest is: {ppl2} and {ppl1} and {ppl3} are the same age')

else:
    print(f'\r\n The three people may be with the same age')
```

Comment: Thank you all for the hint... glad that i get it clarified without realizing i have misinterpreted the following statement - "The if block can have only one else block. But it can have multiple elif blocks."

Answer (score 2):

This is because when one of the elif statements are true, there is no reason for the code to look at the other conditional statements. The use of nested blocks must be improved.

For eg:

```
elif ppl1 > ppl3 and ppl1> ppl2:
  if(ppl3 > ppl2):
    print(f'\r\n the oldest is:{ppl1} and the youngest is: {ppl2}')

elif (ppl1 > ppl3) and (ppl1 > ppl2): 
  if ppl2 > ppl3:
    print(f'\r\n the oldest is: {ppl1} and the youngest is: {ppl3}')
```

Here when you input 100, 31, 30 - `ppl1 > pp3 and pp1>pp2` is true which implies the program enters the first elif statement and checks the if condition. Since the if condition is false, it exists.

```
ppl1=int(input('\r\n person #1: pls enter your age: '))
ppl2=int(input('\r\n person #2: pls enter your age: '))
ppl3=int(input('\r\n person #3: pls enter your age: '))

if (ppl3 > ppl1) and (ppl3 > ppl2): 
  if (ppl1 > ppl2):
    print(f'\r\n the oldest is:{ppl3} and the youngest is: {ppl2}')
  elif(ppl2 > ppl1):
    print(f'\r\n the oldest is: {ppl3} and the youngest is: {ppl1}')

elif ppl1 > ppl3 and ppl1> ppl2:
  if(ppl3 > ppl2):
    print(f'\r\n the oldest is:{ppl1} and the youngest is: {ppl2}')
  elif (ppl2>ppl3):
        print(f'\r\n the oldest is:{ppl1} and the youngest is: {ppl3}') 

elif ppl2 > ppl1 and ppl2 > ppl3: 
  if(ppl3 > ppl1):
    print(f'\r\n the oldest is: {ppl2} and the youngest is: {ppl1}')
  elif(ppl1>ppl3):
    print(f'\r\n the oldest is: {ppl2} and the youngest is: {ppl3}')

else:
  print(f'\r\n The three people may be with the same age')
```

This should give you the desired output. Make note of how the if-elif blocks are used.